# Named pipes trying to send msg C# server to C++ client

Tags: c#, c++, named-pipes

I'm trying to send msgs from my C# form to my C++ dll, **what I need is that the C++ part keeps listening for incoming msgs, if it reads any msg it will do X action depending on msg content, then reply to the C# program with the action result, from the C# part I should be able to send a message and read the response**

When I click button1 I get to this situation:

[image]

So at least we know that pipes can connect.

Now comes the hard part, when I press button2 the server is freezing, the entire server app will freeze until I close it, then I will get this msg:

[image]

So served closed and canalization finished.

This is the **server code**:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer;
        StreamWriter sw;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(Server);
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
        }

        private void Server()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                using (pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("mynamedpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NamedPipeServerStream object created.");

                    // Wait for a client to connect
                    Console.Write("Waiting for client connection...");
                    pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

                    Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

                    try
                    {
                        // Read user input and send that to the client process.
                        using (sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer))
                        {
                            sw.AutoFlush = true;
                            sw.WriteLine("testing msg");
                        }
                    }
                    // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken
                    // or disconnected.
                    catch (IOException err)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", err.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Path.GetFullPath("BetterDll.dll");
            bool result = Injector.InjectDLL(path, "Tibiantis.exe");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sw.WriteLine("testing msg");
            }
            // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken
            // or disconnected.
            catch (IOException err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", err.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the **client code:**

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include "client.h"
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

#define BUFSIZE 512

int _tmain()
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    LPCTSTR lpvMessage = TEXT("Default message from client.");
    TCHAR  chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL   fSuccess = FALSE;
    DWORD  cbRead, cbToWrite, cbWritten, dwMode;
    std::wstring lpszPipename{ LR"(\\.\pipe\mynamedpipe)" };
    //LPCTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\.\pipe\mynamedpipe");    

    // Try to open a named pipe; wait for it, if necessary. 

    while (1)
    {
        hPipe = CreateFile(
            lpszPipename.c_str(),   // pipe name 
            GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,              // no sharing 
            NULL,           // default security attributes
            OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
            0,              // default attributes 
            NULL);          // no template file 

      // Break if the pipe handle is valid. 

        if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            break;

        // Exit if an error other than ERROR_PIPE_BUSY occurs. 

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Could not open pipe. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }

        // All pipe instances are busy, so wait for 20 seconds. 

        if (!WaitNamedPipe(lpszPipename.c_str(), 20000))
        {
            printf("Could not open pipe: 20 second wait timed out.");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // The pipe connected; change to message-read mode. 

    dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE;
    fSuccess = SetNamedPipeHandleState(
        hPipe,    // pipe handle 
        &dwMode,  // new pipe mode 
        NULL,     // don't set maximum bytes 
        NULL);    // don't set maximum time 
    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("SetNamedPipeHandleState failed. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    // Send a message to the pipe server. 

    cbToWrite = (lstrlen(lpvMessage) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Sending %d byte message: \"%s\"\n"), cbToWrite, lpvMessage);

    fSuccess = WriteFile(
        hPipe,                  // pipe handle 
        lpvMessage,             // message 
        cbToWrite,              // message length 
        &cbWritten,             // bytes written 
        NULL);                  // not overlapped 

    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        std::error_code ec{ static_cast<std::int32_t>(GetLastError()), std::system_category() };
        _tprintf(TEXT("WriteFile to pipe failed. GLE=%d\n"));
        std::cout << ec.message() << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nMessage sent to server, receiving reply as follows:\n");

    do
    {
        // Read from the pipe. 

        fSuccess = ReadFile(
            hPipe,    // pipe handle 
            chBuf,    // buffer to receive reply 
            BUFSIZE * sizeof(TCHAR),  // size of buffer 
            &cbRead,  // number of bytes read 
            NULL);    // not overlapped 

        if (!fSuccess && GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            break;

        _tprintf(TEXT("\"%s\"\n"), chBuf);
    } while (!fSuccess);  // repeat loop if ERROR_MORE_DATA 

    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("ReadFile from pipe failed. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\n<End of message, press ENTER to terminate connection and exit>");
    _getch();

    CloseHandle(hPipe);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like your server will constantly be sending the "testing msg" through the entire course that while loop lives. Try adding Console.ReadLine() at the end of the try or after the catch.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I want you to use the following for your server application. I assumed you're using `dotnet core` here. You may also be required to add additional `Nuget` packages.

I've also omitted some error handling code, which you may have to add to make the example more robust.

Also, I only added the `event` handler for the button click which sends the message to the client.

**A couple of other notes here:**

It didn't look like you're expecting a reply from the client so I didn't add code to handle that situation. This means you need to remove the `WriteFile` portion from the client (unless of course you do plan on having bi-directional communication).

Also, I'm using `System.Threading.Channels` for a producer/consumer queue. You can read about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel?view=netcore-3.1)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int PipeInstances = 1;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private readonly Channel<string> _messageQueue;

    public Form1( )
    {
        InitializeComponent( );
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource( );
        _messageQueue = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>( );
        Load += OnFormLoad;
        FormClosing += OnFormClosing;
    }

    private async void OnFormLoad( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        try 
        { 
            using var server = new NamedPipeServerStream( "mynamedpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 
                PipeInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous );

            while ( !_cts.IsCancellationRequested )
            {
                await server.WaitForConnectionAsync( _cts.Token ).ConfigureAwait( false );
                using var writer = new StreamWriter( server );

                while ( !_cts.IsCancellationRequested )
                {
                    var message = await _messageQueue.Reader
                        .ReadAsync( _cts.Token ).ConfigureAwait( false );

                    await writer.WriteLineAsync( message.AsMemory( ),
                        _cts.Token ).ConfigureAwait( false );

                    await writer.FlushAsync( ).ConfigureAwait( false );
                }
            }                
        }
        catch( OperationCanceledException ) { /* No implementation*/ }
    }

    private void OnFormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e )
    {
        _cts.Cancel( );
        _cts.Dispose( );
    }

    private void ButtonClick( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        _messageQueue.Writer.TryWrite( "Testing message" );
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using .net framework, not .net core.. I've made some testing and I can see my dll is not injecting (button1) if I build as .net core app, my client which I want to communicate to is that dll so I really need it to inject first. I also expect response from client so it should be bi-directional. Thank you